# In first post review, votes aren't validated

Tags: bug, first-post-review

When reviewing a first post, if you click the link, then vote on the content, then go back to the review, and then vote on the content again, it looks like both votes are recorded (e.g. 2 upvotes displays as score +2).

In fact, only one vote has been recorded, though.

When you then undo the vote, the real vote does disappear, but the score is not requeried (e.g. undo upvote, score shows 1 but actually is 0).

<sub>(I've encountered this when I decided to answer from first post review, then upvoted, but didn't want to review as no action needed so upvoted again).</sub>

[image]

Comment: Can confirm that this happens. Also, after removing the upvote, I was able to get a negative -1 (without even downvoting), this wasn't recorded since after I refreshed page it showed 0.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: @Draken Nope. Votes are supposed to be validated when they're submitted, and if they can't be submitted, an error message should appear. While one could indeed count this as a cache issue (votes in the browser are not equal to votes in the database), it's a validation issue imo, since everywhere else you get an error message when casting an invalid vote. Also, after refreshing, the vote does appear but the highlighting of the vote (indicating it's your vote) doesn't.