# When out of votes for the day, triage tricks you into thinking you have votes

Tags: support, bug, voting, triage

I am out of votes today, but I decided to do 3 or 4 reviews in Triage. I saw a question which I wished to vote on.

Normally, if you are out of votes and you click either the upvote or downvote button, it immediately undoes and tells you that you are out of votes. But in the queue, it kept my vote normally.

[image]

In the above screen recording, I am out of votes, yet it still *appears* to log my vote, but it hasn't actually logged my vote.

Is this intended behavior, or a bug?

Comment: Isn't triage pending deprecation? Axing the queue is indirectly a solution

Comment: @Zoe really? I had no idea - was there a post on uber meta about it?

Comment: [This one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363552), which mentions it as a consideration. Misremembered part of the info then, but it's still a real option

Comment: This may be a side-effect of this old bug: [In first post review, votes aren't validated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380802/4642212). Review queues are in the process to be overhauled, so I hope they’ll fix all of these…